# XML / PHP Retrive an attribute value from a text search

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, domdocument

I am searching for hours a solution (in PHP) to this:

I have some XML files which structure may vary

```
<page id="this is what I want to extract">
  <boh>
     <bah>
        <other childs (maybe one, maybe ten)>
           <ref id="This is all I know!"> Some text Lorem Ipsum</ref>
```

I need two formulas which would be able:

to extract the **page id** from a search inside all the entire file for either a specific **ref id**, or some partial text inside the **ref tag**

In brief all I know about this file is:
It has a **ref tag**, which sometimes has an **id** and always some text inside.
I either have the ref id or some portions of the text.
I need to find the **id** of the **page** node in which ref is contained.

So:
Search for "This is all I know!" as ref **id** would output "this is what I want to extract"

as well as

Search for "Lorem" as **text** inside ref would output "this is what I want to extract"

How can I accomplish this? I've googled a lot, I think I should make something related with SimpleXML and XPATH, but I never used them in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XPath expression in your code:

```
//page[contains(.//ref/text(), 'Lorem')]/@id
```

It will search all `<ref>` elements that are descendants of `<page>` and compare the text with the string 'Lorem' (which, in your code, you should pass as a variable). It will return a set containing all the ids of the `<page>` elements that contain the matching text.

Comment: As for using XPath with PHP, there is a great tutorial here: http://www.sitepoint.com/php-dom-using-xpath/

Answer (score 0):

use `xpath` to query your XML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

$result1 = (string)$xml->xpath("//ref[@id = 'This is all I know!']/ancestor::page/@id")[0];

$result2 = (string)$xml->xpath("//ref[contains(.,'Lorem')]/ancestor::page/@id")[0];
```

see it working: https://eval.in/104646

**Comments:**

The code above requires PHP >= 5.4 for the `[0]` at the end of the last two lines. If you are on a lower version, update or do:

```
$result = $xml->xpath("blabla");
$result = (string)$result[0];
```

The 1st `xpath`expression selects all `<ref>` nodes wherever in the tree (for the `//ref`) with the given `id` attribute. Once found, it returns the `id` attribute of its 1st `<page>` ancestor.

The 2nd expression selects all `<ref>` containing part of your search phrase, then see above.